# Mock the result of accessing public GCS bucket

Tags: google-api, mocking, google-cloud-storage, python-unittest, google-cloud-python

I have the following code:

```
bucket = get_bucket('bucket-name')
blob = bucket.blob(os.path.join(*pieces))
blob.upload_from_string('test')
blob.make_public()
result = blob.public_url
# result is `<Mock name='mock().get_bucket().blob().public_url`
```

And I would do like to mock the result of *public_url*, my unit test code is something like this

```
with ExitStack() as st:
    from google.cloud import storage
    blob_mock = mock.Mock(spec=storage.Blob)
    blob_mock.public_url.return_value = 'http://'

    bucket_mock = mock.Mock(spec=storage.Bucket)
    bucket_mock.blob.return_value = blob_mock

    storage_client_mock = mock.Mock(spec=storage.Client)
    storage_client_mock.get_bucket.return_value = bucket_mock

    st.enter_context(
        mock.patch('google.cloud.storage.Client', storage_client_mock))
    my_function()
```

Is there something like [FakeRedis](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/fakeredis) or [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) for Google Storage, so I can mock `google.cloud.storage.Blob.public_url`?

Answer (score 3):

I found this [fake gcs server](https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server/tree/main/examples/python) written in Go which can be run within a Docker container and consumed by the Python library. See [Python examples](https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server/tree/main/examples/python).